# Firebase Downloaded file doesn't work

Tags: android, firebase, download, firebase-storage

I have a very weird problem.
I create an ogg file and upload this file into the firebase storage. 
There is no problem for now. I can listen to the ogg file without any problem

[The File link](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/screeam-9e66a.appspot.com/o/screamfiles%2F5554.ogg?alt=media&token=d505d291-f244-4079-b163-6b5b57764d62)

Then, I download the same file using the code in below. After the download, I can see the file on my Android Device but the file doesn't work (I cannot open it in any ogg player or I cannot make it ringtone)

```
   StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
                StorageReference  islandRef = storageRef.child(ring_url);

                File rootPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "files");
                if(!rootPath.exists()) {
                    rootPath.mkdirs();
                }
                String childName = ring_url.replace("files","").replace("/","");
                final File localFile = new File(rootPath,childName);


                islandRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Log.e("firebase ",";local tem file created  created " +localFile.toString());

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        Log.e("firebase ",";local tem file not created  created " +exception.toString());
                    }
                });
```

Is there any clue what this happens?

Comment: What's the output of `localFile.toString()`?

Comment: @rosario The output is /storage/emulated/0/screamfiles/5554.ogg. When I check the file, I can see it in the folder but when I try to open it doesn't run. However, the same file which in the firebase run properly.